# GET_SUCCESS in reducer test returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

```
 it(`should handle ${GET_POSTAL_SUCCESS}`, () => {
      const payload = {
        postalCode: {
          postalInfo: {
            postalCode: '5282',
          },
        },
      };

      expect(reducer(state, { type: GET_POSTAL_SUCCESS, payload })).toEqual({
        ...state,
        postalInfo: payload.postalCode,
        loading: false,
      })
    });
```

First is received and second is expected in the code block. It wont format well here for some reason.

Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

*- Expected*

**+ Received**

```
 *Object {
    "loading": false,
-   "postalInfo": Object {
-     "postalInfo": Object {
-       "postalCode": "5282",
-     },
-   },*


**+   "postalInfo": undefined,**
  }
```

Why would postalInfo be undefined in recieved with this block of code? I just dont get it

```
 expect(reducer(state, { type: GET_POSTAL_SUCCESS, payload }))
```

Here is my original reducer:

```
function reducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.GET_POSTAL:
      return {
        ...defaultState,
        code: action.code,
        loading: true,
      };
    case constants.GET_POSTAL_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        postalInfo: action.payload.result,
        loading: false,
      };
```

And here is my whole test so far:

```
 let state = reducer(undefined, {});

  it('should have initial state', () => {
    expect(state).toBeDefined();
  });


  describe('get postals', () => {

    it(`it should handle ${GET_POSTAL}`, () => {
      const code = '5282';
      expect(reducer(state, { type: GET_POSTAL, code })).toEqual({
        ...state,
        code,
        loading: true,
      });
    });

    it(`should handle ${GET_POSTAL_SUCCESS}`, () => {
      const payload = {
        postalCode: {
          postalInfo: {
            postalCode: '5282',
          },
        },
      };

      expect(reducer(state, { type: GET_POSTAL_SUCCESS, payload })).toEqual({
        ...state,
        postalInfo: payload.postalCode,
        loading: false,
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reducer in the success case you're setting the state as `action.payload.result`:

```
case constants.GET_POSTAL_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    postalInfo: action.payload.result,
    loading: false,
};
```

But in your test case this is how you're generating the payload:

```
const payload = {
  postalCode: {
    postalInfo: {
      postalCode: '5282',
    },
  },
};
```

It should have a `result` property in the payload since your reducer is expecting it:

```
const payload = {
  result: {
    postalInfo: {
      postalCode: '5282',
    },
  },
};
```